# Is it possible for String.split() to return tuple?

Tags: c#

I have `string` which I need to `split()` and assign it's value into two variables. Is it possible for `split()` to return `tuple` instead of `string[]` so I can do something like:

```
String myString = "hello=world"
value, id = myString.Split('=');
```

I'm looking for some elegant solution.

Comment: provide please string example

Comment: No, because there's no guarantee of the number of results. You could create a `SplitPair` function if you want.

Comment: @vc74 another variable and lines of code

Comment: "Is it possible for split() to return tuple instead of string[]" ... if you put it that way - yes and no. The split method returns what it returns. But you _could_ write an extension method, though.

Comment: @vc74 nothing wrong, I'm just looking for different approaches

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you can use C# 7 - you can use tuple deconstruction. If type has static or extension method named `Deconstruct` with appropriate signature - this type can be deconstructed. So you can have extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static void Deconstruct<T>(this IList<T> list, out T first, out IList<T> rest) {

        first = list.Count > 0 ? list[0] : default(T); // or throw
        rest = list.Skip(1).ToList();
    }

    public static void Deconstruct<T>(this IList<T> list, out T first, out T second, out IList<T> rest) {
        first = list.Count > 0 ? list[0] : default(T); // or throw
        second = list.Count > 1 ? list[1] : default(T); // or throw
        rest = list.Skip(2).ToList();
    }
}
```

And then you can deconstruct string array (which implements `IList<string>`) with this syntax (you might need to add appropriate `using` so that extension method above is reachable):

```
var line = "a=b";
var (first, second, _) = line.Split('=');
Console.WriteLine(first); // "a"
Console.WriteLine(second); // "b"
```

or

```
var line = "a=b";
var (first, (second, _)) = line.Split('=');
Console.WriteLine(first); // "a"
Console.WriteLine(second); // "b"
```

Which is quite close to what you need.

With just first extension method above (which deconstructs to first element and the rest) you can deconstruct to arbitrary length:

```
var (first, (second, _)) = line.Split('=');
var (first, (second, (third,  _))) = line.Split('=');
var (first, rest) = line.Split('=');
// etc
```

Second extension method is needed only if you want a little bit more convenient syntax for deconstruction of first 2 values (`var (first, second, rest)` instead of `var (first, (second, rest))`)

Comment: Beautiful solution.

Comment: This is certainly the right way to implement Python-like multiple return handling for collections, but I would avoid using this sort of language extension. This provides dubious clarity and convenience benefits over the plain two-liner `var split = myString.Split('='); string value = split[0], id = split[1];` which will be familiar and obvious to any C# programmer.

Comment: +1 for using discard identifier. Before two weeks, I didn't know about discard identifier and now these days,I see lots of usage of this identifier.

Comment: @j4nw A big fan of deconstruction could even write `(string value, string id) = (split[0], split[1]);` after splitting the string.

Comment: more correct: `(string value, string id) = split.Length > 0 ? (split[0], split.Length > 1 ? split[1] : string.Empty) : (string.Empty, string.Empty);`

Answer (score 43):

In C# 8 [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) can be used for that:

```
var myString = "hello=world";
var (value, id) = myString.Split('=') switch { var a => (a[0], a[1]) };
```

Switch expression also allows you to handle different array lengths:

```
var myString = "hello=world";
var (value, id) = myString.Split('=') switch
{
    var a when a.Length == 2 => (a[0], a[1]),
    _ => (null, null)
};
```

**Update:** with C# 11 [list patterns](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/early-peek-at-csharp-11-features/comment-page-5/#c-11-preview-list-patterns) feature array can also be deconstructed:

```
var (value, id) = myString.Split('=') switch
{
    [var v, var i] => (v, i),
    _ => default
};
```

Unfortunately as of today something like this is still only in [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4082) stage:

```
[var value, var id] = myString.Split('='); // Does not compile!
var [value, id] = myString.Split('=');     // Does not compile!
```

But with [is expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) one can do the following:

```
if(myString.Split('=') is [var value, var id])
{
    Console.WriteLine((value, id));
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution, I hope it will get enough upvotes to climb on the answer list 

Comment: I love this answer. I opted for the C# v11. One quickie though: Is casting the second part to int possible?

Answer (score 6):

Using LinQ:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> pairs = lines
    .Select(x => 
    {
        string[] s = x.Split('=');
        return Tuple.Create(s[0], s[1]);
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: suppose you have more than two elements than?

Comment: Pro tip: you can call `Split` only once and store the result in the `Select` call

Comment: this assumes that each string in the list contains a single equals sign meaning that each indicates one variable. Eg. "x=1", "y=2", etc

Comment: No, you changed the result, I didn't mean that, I meant literally inside the `Select`

Comment: @Camilo I misunderstood... Like this?

Comment: That's exactly it. And you should prefer `Tuple.Create` so you can avoid specifying generic arguments

Answer (score 3):

In C# 7 you can use `out var` and an extension to declare and assign multiple variables from an array with a group of extension methods:

```
static class MyExtensions {
    static void Assign<T>(this IList<T> items, out T v) {
        v = items[0];
    }
    static void Assign<T>(this IList<T> items, out T v0, out T v1) {
        v0 = items[0];
        v1 = items[1];
    }
    static void Assign<T>(this IList<T> items, out T v0, out T v1, out T v2) {
        v0 = items[0];
        v1 = items[1];
        v2 = items[2];
    }
    static void Assign<T>(this IList<T> items, out T v0, out T v1, out T v2, out T v3) {
        v0 = items[0];
        v1 = items[1];
        v2 = items[2];
        v3 = items[3];
    }
    ... // And so on
}
```

This extension lets you decompose your split into individual variables, rather than a tuple:

```
Assign(myString.Split('='), out var value, out var id);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the usage be `out var` and not `var out`? That is, I think the example usage should be `Assign(myString.Split('='), out var value, out var id);`

Answer (score 1):

You can create tuple dynamically using reflection, That will give you a tuple for a variable number of elements.

Try below code snippet,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tupple = GetTuple<string>("hello=world".Split('='));
    }

    public static object GetTuple<T>(params T[] values)
    {
        Type genericType = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + values.Length);
        Type[] typeArgs = values.Select(_ => typeof(T)).ToArray();
        Type specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
        object[] constructorArguments = values.Cast<object>().ToArray();
        return Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, constructorArguments);
    }
```

Comment: How will they be able to destructure the result when the return type is `object`?

Comment: @Lee your concern is correct in this code you need to cast tuple, let me check if I get any alternative

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i end up with hope will help  you :

```
static void Main()
    {
        var a = new List<string> {
           "ID = Value",
           "id=value",
           "id      =    value"
        };

        var values = new List<string>();
        var ids = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            (string value, string id) = SplitText(a[i]);
            values.Add(value);
            ids.Add(id);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Values -> {string.Join(", ", values)}, ID's -> {string.Join(", ", ids)}");
    }

    private static (string, string) SplitText(string inputText)
    {
        var tokens = inputText.Split(new[] { ' ', '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return (tokens[0], tokens[1]);
    }
```